# Checking list within constructor for duplicates

Tags: list, duplicates

I have a class called Recipe. The Recipe maynot contain duplicate Ingredients, otherwise a Illegal Argument Exception should be thrown. I tried to use a helplist but I am getting a NullPointerException for the line: "for (int i = 0; i < ingredients.size(); i++)"

```
public class Recipe {

    private String title;
    private String instructions;
    private LinkedList<Ingredient> ingredients;

    boolean noduplicate = true;

    // constructor
    public Recipe(String title, String instructions,
            List<Ingredient> ingredients) {
        this.title = title;
        this.instructions = instructions;
        LinkedList<Ingredient> helplist = new LinkedList<Ingredient>();
        for (int i = 0; i < ingredients.size(); i++) {
            Ingredient x = ingredients.get(i);
            if (helplist.contains(x)) {
                noduplicate = false;
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "This ingredient is duplicate!");
            }
            if (noduplicate) {
                helplist.add(x);
            }
            noduplicate = true;
        }
        this.ingredients = helplist;

    }
```

}

Comment: I also tried it with a Set in the constructor but I am also getting a NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

Use a set instead of a list, since that is the datastructure you want. In short, a set only contains unique elements. When you try to add stuff which is already there, nothing happens. You have to override the equal/hash method of your Ingredients class in order to make it work.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html